# Disable 'reformat code' checkbox in commit dialog of PHPStorm by default

Tags: git, commit, phpstorm, reformat

I'm pissed off with PHPStorm having this feature enagled by default. I have to unckeck this EACH toime I commit something. If I forget, it silently does line truncations and other stuff I don't like. Is there a way to set this checkbox unckecked by default?

Answer (score 2):

sorry, I was incorrect. It actually remembers checkbox configuration each time I commit. I seemed to be doing it for a while. But if you open commit window, change checkboxes and close it, it doesn't memorize anything.

Comment: *I think this post can be deleted, because of its uselessness.* Up to you. If you don't think it could help other people, perhaps you should just delete your question.